# onclick of button previous data should get flushed using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have 2 values inside the same div and I have the same classes also. On click of each value different data appears. I am getting the data but the problem is it is appending with the previous data.

eg:

```
<div id="dashboard">
<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

When I click on "icon" , separate set of values appear and when I click on second "icon", I want the values generated from the first "icon" to be hidden. All these values are generated from a plugin.

How do I use show/hide within the same class and the same div?

Comment: please past the code where the values are be assigned. It would give more idea of the functionality to be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting much details from your question.

May be you are looking like this... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39qyR/5/)

```
 <div id="dashboard">
<span class="icon" onclick="document.getElementById('dataArea').innerHTML='Icon1 Data';">Icon 1</span> | 
<span class="icon" onclick="document.getElementById('dataArea').innerHTML='Icon2 Data';"> Icon 2</span>
</div> <br/>
<div id="dataArea"></div>
```

That means, for appending data use `element.innerHTML = ""` or `$().html()`; this method will flush old data presnce inside div, and add new data. but `.append()` will add new data with old one.